# Load view using ng-view in index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three pages. I want to load them in `ng-view`. When user clicks on page the relevant page should load. I have setup the `routerProvider` but it did not work.

**// HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="learningApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    ul li{ float: left; list-style: none; margin: 0 10px}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav>   
    <ul><li><a href="#home">home</a></li><li><a href="#about">about</a></li><li><a href="#service">service</a></li></ul>
</nav>  



    <div ng-view></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**// App.js code**

```
(function(){
  var app= angular.module('learningApp',['ngRoute'])

  app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
               when('/home', {
                  templateUrl: 'home.html'
               }).
               when('/aboutus', {
                  templateUrl: 'aboutus.html'

               }).
               when('/service',{
                templateUrl:'service.html'
               }).
               otherwise({
                  redirectTo: '/home'
               });

  }])

})
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=learningApp&p1=Erro…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A339)

Comment: I figure out the problem. Actually I was not calling my anonymous function

Comment: Add () at last line of app.js. It should be like })(); It is not written as IIFE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks good but you got a problem with your anchor href's.

Modify:

```
<nav>   
    <ul><li><a href="#home">home</a></li><li><a href="#about">about</a></li><li><a href="#service">service</a></li></ul>
</nav>
```

To:

```
<nav>   
    <ul><li><a href="#/home">home</a></li><li><a href="#/about">about</a></li><li><a href="#/service">service</a></li></ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I notice that my console showing error.    Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/……ogle‌​apis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A339

Answer (score 0):

If there is no console errors, I think you need to use the `a` tags like,

note the additional `/` after `#`

```
<a href="#/home">home</a>
<a href="#/about">about</a>
```

Comment: Can you tell how to add indexing of link in URL